# I've been asked to perform authentication without usernames and passwords, what are my options?

Tags: php, javascript, apache, authentication

I've been asked to leave passwords and user names aside since most of the site visitors are stop-buy-come-back-several-months-later-kind of visitors, and the motivation was somewhat along the lines "they would forget there passwords any way and have to request new ones".

I suspect there is no realistic way for me to do this thinking IP:s probably change and browsers get updated, cookies are cleared and so forth.

Or do I have any options?

(not that I'm looking for code but rather concepts and pseudo but the language in the project is php/js coupled with an apache server)

Comment: Is Facebook Connect or OpenID an option?

Comment: Suggest email as username, and be kind with password rules

Comment: I've decided to try out an email recognition solution as per jishi's answer - thnx for all the interesting ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do the following in our e-commerce solution:

We use email as a unique identifier.

When a customer makes a purchase using the same email, the order will be attached to their existing user. You don't however get any address details or stuff like that, but have to enter it manually.

The customer will receive an email with a generated password if it is a first time buy. If it is a second time buy, they will just be instructed to log in. This can however be combined with a url and a login token. Likewise for logging into the site, you could just have them enter an email to receieve a login url token.

Combine this with a long living cookie and/or the browsers datastorage to remember the customers details (address and stuff like that).

Another option would be to have them entering something about themselves that they would always know, but others wouldn't. However it is hard to have an internationally workable solution for this.

Comment: Very interesting answers over all, but I lean towards the email-solution described here.

Answer (score 8):

## Use [OpenID](http://openid.net/).

Let Facebook, Google, Wordpress, or even Stack Exchange handle the authentication for you, and people wont have to remember *another* password.

---

Alternatively:

Many users understand the "forgot my password; check my email" routine by now, so why not just short-cut it by having them input their email and send them a login url with a randomly generated token to log in with.

Once they're logged in, keep them logged in for as long as you deem secure.

Answer (score 1):

You could use so-called supercookies, which is offline storage on the client side. Either through html5 offline storage, or plugin like flash to restore deleted cookies. Although, these cookies is likely to be banned at some point, since they're mostly hidden for the user, and very hard to get rid of. (Not recommending this approach, just saying it's possible)

Answer (score 1):

Authentication credentials break down to three options;

- Something you know - passwords
- Something you have - physical keys, cards
- Something you are - iris, retinal and other biometrics

The best you can do is use cookies I think. Or...I guess you could have them download a file, and upload that file as their access credential - same idea as a cookie but unlikely to be deleted. You would have to think carefully about what to put into the file however - their user id isn't enough, as it would be easily hacked. A random long string would do, one that is saved into the database on their account. Nothing that can be predicted, and nothing that can be used to guess a different account's credential.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options come to mind:

- Use a [persistent cookie](http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/persistent-cookies-used-for.html), but *only* do this in conjunction with SSL (so it simply can't be sniffed off the wire)
- Another option is OpenID like you use here - therefore vistors *can* use an account they use often to log into your site.

Comment: A cookie does not identify the user but the browser.

Comment: Correct, but with the absence of username that's all you have

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that your only option is giving them a forever cookie and hoping it doesn't get purged between visits.

You can read about them [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp).